# Do I loose subscriptions when report is modified?

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, reportmanager

I have a report which runs for all environments. Now the report is modified to have a multi valued parameter '`environment`' which has default of '`ALL`'. There are few subscriptions on the old version of report.

My question is when the report manager is updated with new `version` of report do I loose all these subscriptions or is there any way that the subscriptions use default value of environment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that it will use the default value for the existing subscription.  I created a test report without any parameters, loaded it to our server and created a subscription.  I then added a parameter to the report, updated the server and the existing subscription was using the default value.  See the link below.

http://www.anony.ws/i/2013/12/05/UxPyj.jpg

Comment: Thanks for your time and effort Steve. When you said "updated the server" how did you do that? Here we delete the existing the report from report manager and upload new file from local. On doing this I am loosing my subscription.

Comment: Im my scenario I simply redeployed the report. In your scenario you would lose the subscriptions because when you delete a report, reporting services doesn't want any orphan subscriptions on the server so it removes those as well.  Why are you updating in this manner?  Just curious

Comment: Oh that's because we have hundreds of reports in one project and most of them are broken so cannot deploy the whole project.

Comment: Cant you just deploy a single report?  You should be able to right-click the report in BIDS Solution Explorer and select Deploy.  It will overwrite just that report's definition on the server.  See the link below for an example

http://www.anony.ws/kJ5v